# How to set QueryJobConfig in BigQuery with ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

There is a check box `Use Cached Results` to decide whether use cache or not in BigQuery WebUI.
And I find that python can do that things too like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
sql = "sql script"
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.use_query_cache = False
query_job = client.query(sql,job_config=job_config)
results = query_job.result()
```

But I can not find example code with `ruby` to do cancel auto cache result from BigQuery.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-bigquery/lib/google/cloud/bigquery/query_job.rb#L558) from the official Google Cloud Platform GitHub repository for using BigQuery with Ruby. Information on line 558 should help you disable looking for results in the query cache.